# How Eclipse implements its Quick Fix feature

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have encountered a question in my project, that is Quick Fix in java source code, like the style of eclipse Quick Fix / Quick Assist feature. Our Quick Fix rule is to generate setter or getter for ever property if they don't exist, by right -click the message displayed in eclipse problems view. So, I want to know how eclipse implements its Quick Fix feature,I would be glad, if someone could point me to the right description.

Answer (score 3):

There is an FAQ item for this: [How do I implement Quick Fixes for my own language?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_Quick_Fixes_for_my_own_language%3F)